# retrieve value from another page TAG

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a code to retrieve the value of a TAG which "id" is "token". This TAG is present in the page called "script.php". Javascript is working, but `document.write(val)` does not display anything...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Void</title>

</head>


<body>

    <iframe src="script.php" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

    <script>
        document.write('<br/>');
        var doc = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 
        var val = doc.contentWindow.document.getElementById("token").value;
        document.write(val);
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

The page "script.php" contains the following code:

```
<form id="profile" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="az">
        </div>
        <br>        
        <div>
        <label>Status:</label>
        <input id="status" type="checkbox" name="status" disabled >
        </div>
        <br>
        <input id="token" type="hidden" name="token" value="e4dea0c3a5a6246d98a6573f06ddfc97" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your iframe's domain is same as yours

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

alert(innerDoc.getElementById("token").value);
```

Comment: I don't use any console, i execute the page by loading it on my browser, how can i see my errors ?

Comment: @mric750 Your browser should be having a developer console.

Comment: Okay , i found it, i have an error indeed, here it is: TypeError: innerDoc.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @mric750 can you check if innerDoc value? `console.log(innerDoc);console.log(innerDoc.getElementById("token"));`

Comment: @mric750 is iframe's domain same as your domain?

Comment: both pages are on the same folder in my xampp directory

Comment: @mric750 can you also print `console.log(iframe );console.log(iframe.contentDocument);console.log(iframe.contentWindow);`

Comment: @mric750 all cannot be undefined, since then second console log will fail. Can you share a fiddle or a live example?

Answer (score -1):

Several predefined variables in PHP are "superglobals" no matter their scope.For that reason you can access them from almost everywhere in your code.So try to reach them like that: `var val = $GLOBALS['name_of your value']`;

Comment: You seem to be confusing PHP and JavaScript in such a way as to come up with something that won't work in either language.